# Excel SaveAs() hangs

Tags: excel, vb6

I have exported data to the excel file using visual basic 6, The Problem is **everything works fine when i export in debug mode but when i make the exe it hangs and cursor keeps rotating**.

I have given the code for export Below. The program appears to freeze at the `SaveAs` line:

```
On Error GoTo X
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim objExcl As Excel.Application
Dim objWk As Excel.Workbook
Dim objSht As Excel.Worksheet
Dim iHead As Integer
Dim vHead As Variant
Dim path As String
Dim VFileNm As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim CmpGstin As String
Set objExcl = New Excel.Application
RptType = 0
Frame6.Visible = True
MDIForm1.Enabled = False
Label3.Caption = "Please wait... Data is Uploading to Excel file"
VFileNm = App.path & "\GSTR2_Excel.xlsx"
Set objWk = objExcl.Workbooks.Open(VFileNm) '"F:\GST_REPORTS\GST_AGENCIES_TAX_NM20\GSTR1_Excel.xlsx")
For i = 1 To 8
    If i = 1 Then
        If TotRcpt > 0 Then
            ChkG2B2b.Value = 1
            Set objSht = objWk.Sheets(2)
        End If
        Next iCol
       Next iRow
   End If
   TotRcpt = 0
Next
cd1.CancelError = True
cd1.FileName = "\GSTR2_" & CmpGstin & "_" & Format(FrmGstRptShow.DTpFrmDt, "MMMMYYYY") & ".xlsx"
cd1.InitDir = ("C:\My Documents")
cd1.Filter = "*.xlsx|*.xlsx"
cd1.FilterIndex = 4
cd1.ShowSave
VFileNm = cd1.FileName
Label3.Caption = "Please Wait... Excel File is Saving"
objWk.SaveAs VFileNm
MsgBox "Export Succecefully "
objWk.Close False
MDIForm1.Enabled = True
Label3.Caption = ""
Set objSht = Nothing
Set objWk = Nothing
Set objExcl = Nothing
Unload Me
X:
'MsgBox Err.Description
MDIForm1.Enabled = True
Label3.Caption = ""
Set objSht = Nothing
Set objWk = Nothing
Set objExcl = Nothing
'objWk.Close False
Unload Me
```

If the problem occurred during debugging mode i could have managed to solve the issue, But It occurs when run it using the EXE.

Comment: You should try to narrow it down a lot more, and pinpoint exactly where it hangs. Comment things out, add debugging messages, etc. to try and figure that out. You'll also get a better answer here if you can do that... here are some guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ok i have removed most of my unnecessory code for the issue And for xp it hangs when it opens option for user to select the path and in windows 7 it stucks on message Please wait... Data is Uploading to Excel file. And about debugging it works fine when i run it through code but hangs when i make the exe and try to write. Hope i Cleared all the doubts

Comment: So it either freezes on the line `ShowSave` or the line `objWk.SaveAs` ?

Comment: On objWk.SaveAs

Comment: Perhaps the exe context doesn't have permission to write the file, while the debug context does. You might write some error handling code that will show whatever error you're getting.

Comment: Yeah! Even though I never figured out the problem, but I changed entire code and now it's working fine